# The boundary of a manifold is a closed subset.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

We want to show that the boundary $\partial M$ of an $n-$manifold M is a closed subset of the manifold. We show that its complement $M\setminus\partial M$ is open in $M$. Indeed,  each point $x \in M\setminus\partial M$ has an open neighborhood $V_x\subseteq M$ homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. It remains only to show that $V_x$ lies entirely in $M\setminus \partial M$ which means that $V_x\cap \partial M=\emptyset$. Thank you for your help!

EDIT: In a manifold with boundary each point has an open neighborhood that is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ or to $\mathbb R^n_+=\{(x_1,\cdots,x_n)\in\mathbb R^n\;|\; x_n\ge 0\}$, the points who have open neighborhoods homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n_+$ form the boundary of the manifold.

Comment: How do you find your $V_x$?

Comment: It is by definition of a point

Comment: Can you also include the definition of "manifold with boundary" in your question?

Comment: I included a definition, thank you!

Comment: Your definition is not completely correct. The boundary point are those points lying in $x_n = 0$. (there are points in $\mathbb R^n_+$ which are not boundary points).

Comment: Hint: each point of $V_x$ has an open neighborhood homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @Alex Ravsky  : you are saying implicitly that $V_x$ is entirely in $M\setminus \partial M$, otherwise points of $V_x$ that are lying on the boundary $\partial M$ have neighborhoods homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n_+$ not $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: can we just take $V_x\cap (M\setminus \partial M)$ to be the open neighborhood containing $x$ ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is obvious. Let $x \in M \setminus \partial M$. There exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ in $M$ which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$. Then **any** $y \in V$ has the same property, hence $V \subset M \setminus \partial M$.

By the way, your definition of the boundary is not correct. Take $M = \mathbb R^n_+$. Then **each** $x \in \mathbb R^n_+$ has $\mathbb R^n_+$ as an open neighborhood which is homeomorphic $\mathbb R^n_+$. A correct definition is this: A point $p \in M$ is called a boundary point if there
exists a homeomorphism $\phi : U \to \mathbb R^n_+$ defined on an open neighborhood $U$ of $p$ in $M$ such that $\phi(p) \in \partial \mathbb R^n_+ =\mathbb R^{n-1} \times \{ 0\}$.

Comment: you mean $\partial \mathbb R^n_+ =\mathbb R^{n-1} \times \{ 0\}$.

Comment: Yes - I shall correct this!

Comment: It's easy to see that the manifold interior is open in $M$, but - assuming that $M$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb R^d$ with boundary - will it be open in the ambient space $\mathbb R^d$ as well?

Comment: If $d = n$ yes, if $d > n$ no.