# If $\phi : \partial{M} \times [0,1) \to M $ is an embedding prove that $\phi(\partial{M} \times [0,a])$ is closed in $M$.

Tags: manifolds-with-boundary, surgery-theory

Let $M$ be a compact manifold and let $\phi:\partial{M}\times [0,1) \to M $ be an embedding whose image is open in $M$. How to prove that $ \phi(\partial{M} \times [0,a]) $ is closed in $M$ for any $a>0$.

I was studying adjunction spaces, and, I want to prove the hausdorffness of the adjunction space. I need to prove this fact first in order to get the open sets separating any two distinct points in that space. How to prove this fact. Please help..

Comment: Note that $\partial M$ is a closed subset of $M$, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2536208/the-boundary-of-a-manifold-is-a-closed-subset Hence, $\partial M$ is compact in $M$ as $M$ is compact. Product two compact sets is compact, so $\partial M\times [0,a]$ is compact. Now, continuous image of compact set is compact. So, $\text{im}\phi$ is compact subset of $M$. Next, $M$ is Hausdorf implies image of $\phi$ is closed in $M$.

Comment: In case $M$ is non-compact this argument is not applicable. But construction of the collar neighborhood theorem can be modified so that we have a closed imbedding.

Comment: @0-th User Im curious how do they construct collar neighborhood in non-compact spaces.. please provide a link or any source

Comment: I searched in MSE, may be it is not here. But I read it from some lecture note.